# Android blur background Such as Core Image?

Tags: android, blur

I am of the view I want to handle blur background.
As well as a transparent state.

The view behind the blur is handled naturally blur the image or text, and I want to be treated.

iOS core image on the screen to change the background,
Process or blur a Bitmap, Android, or blur the whole process Activity (now Deprecated) as to background blur on the screen is coated wondering if there is a way.

Using NDK import an image blur in the back knows how to handle.